# wordpress custom taxonomy search not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i am building advanced wordpress custom search with taxonomy filter. But the taxonomy  is not being filtered.
 This is the code for the search form;

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'understrap' ); ?></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="field form-control" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search &hellip;', 'understrap' ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="country">

        <?php
         $args= array('hide_empty'=>false,
                      );
        $district = get_terms('country',$args); ?>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> Select</option>
        <?php foreach ($district as $region) {?>
        <<option value="albania"> <?php echo  $region->name;?></option>
            <?php } ?>  
        </select>


            <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'understrap' ); ?>" />
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

This the query from the url:

http://localhost/home/?s=&post_type=country&country=&submit=Search

Comment: And that URL triggers WP default search functionality, or what?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your taxonomy is set to public e.g.

```
register_taxonomy( 'my_tax', 
        array('for_posttype'), 
        array('hierarchical' => true,     
            'public' => true,
```

Then verify if you can directly query the post type + taxonomy parameter based on url query var, run directly to browser `http://yoursite.com/?post_type=country&taxonomy=your_taxonomy_slug&term=term_slug`

If you don't have any result then you have to do additional debugging like making sure there's already post assign into that term, the term is public etc.

When you get a result you can then build a custom form to build the url you'd want generate.

e.g.

```
<form method="GET" action="/" >
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="keyword" />
    <select name="term">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> Select</option>
        <option value="term1">Term 1</option> 
        <option value="term2">Term 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="country">
    <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="your_taxonomy_slug">
</form>
```